# How to append new records only to BiqQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I get reports from 3rd party API on daily basis and going to store data in BigQuery table. Each report includes data for the last 90 days,  so each new report has new records for new day, but loses some records for 91 day. My task is keeping data in Bigquery for period > 90 days.

I tried to setup BiqQuery data transfer from Cloud Storage with "Write preference" option "Mirror" and seems that it just overwrites my old data with new. If I change it to "Append" it will add data from new report to old with doubles.

Are there any ideas how can I just append new records to my table using BigQuery functional? Can't believe that it's impossible.

Comment: Please put the new data to a tempory table. Then use the `MERGE` command to combine the new data from the tempory table to the main old one. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples

Comment: Thank you for advice. I thought there is an option to do it automatically. If I don't find find such way will use additional steps with SQL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.